how this parameter inside lambda expression is initialized during runtime?
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.socket.TextMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.TextWebSocketHandler;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

@Component
public class WebSocketClient extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    private static final String WEBSOCKET_URI = "..............";
    private static final String SUBSCRIPTION_MESSAGE = "..............";

    @PostConstruct
    public void connect() {

        StandardWebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();
        CompletableFuture<WebSocketSession> future = client.execute(this, new WebSocketHttpHeaders(), URI.create(WEBSOCKET_URI));

        future.thenAccept(session -> {
            try {
                session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(SUBSCRIPTION_MESSAGE));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) {
        System.out.println("Received: " + message.getPayload());
    }
}

I am new to websocket, asynchronous programming and lambda expression. Can someone explain for me how the parameter "session" is initialized during runtime?
future.thenAccept(session -> {
            try {
                session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(SUBSCRIPTION_MESSAGE));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
        );

I have tried to read the java doc, but it's still confusing for me.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html
